# persist connection object across all the pages in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i am developing cross platform application using jquery and jquery mobile , we are almost done with the project but we just came across very big hurdle. our mobile app has a chat functionality (using openfire ).

There is one javascript file in named `chat.js` , that is responsible for making connection to the openfire server , i want to access connection object that i have used in `chat.js` across almost all the pages.

now the hurdle is we are changing page using following code.

```
$("#page").load("pages/Home.html", function () {
    Home.init();
});
```

`#page` tag is in a `index.html (entry page )` and in which i have added `chat.js` now whenever i switch to `Home.html` i am not able to access Connection object in `Home.js` ( which is added in home.html ).

i am getting reference error as follows , `RRC` is the object that i have created in `chat.js`

```
10-13 14:07:34.186: E/NONE(2290): Uncaught Exception: Uncaught ReferenceError: RRC is not defined at (compiled_code):8149
```

so what i want is if i browse any number of pages i want to access RRC object across all the pages and that object to be initialized only once.

i have defined RRC as follows in chat.js

```
var RRC = {
    connection:null,

   initialize:function(){
      connection = // creating new connection
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you pass that in function argument?

Comment: how come ? , to pass that object in arguments i need to declare it in a chat.js and then again i need to add chat.js one more time in home.html

Comment: Where/how are you defining RRC? If it is not defined in some global object you would have to pass it around, for instance `Home.init(RRC)` (if RRC is visible to the .load callback)

Comment: can you please see my edits